# Are nvidea-cuda SDK binaries in ubuntu repositories up to date?

Tags: software-installation, cuda

I wonder how can I check those binaries in repo and compare to download from nvidia's site before installing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please take the tour: https://askubuntu.com/tour I found it helpful every now and then. Regarding your question, `apt-cache search nvidia-cuda` shows 4 packages for me: dev, doc, gdb and toolkit.  Which package are you talking about - gdb, dev or toolkit?

Comment: @LIttle Ancient Forest Kami: Hello and thank you,  I believe nvidia-cuda-dev are necessary files for development but I want version information and etc; I've gone to http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu and looked up packages in repository and couldn't find my way to nvidia-cuda , perhaps the http interface is not for human consumption. Can I get more info from apt-cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Up to date or not?

This usually is checked in a simple manner:

1. check package version
2. compare version with what's on producer/vendor site

#### Checking package version

3 options:
1. `apt-cache policy nvidia-cuda-toolkit`
2. `apt-cache madison nvidia-cuda-toolkit`
3. `apt list nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

[image: session log in Polish]

### Nvidia

I found two great links which are too lengthy to be copied here verbatim:

1. https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07
2. https://gist.github.com/zhanwenchen/e520767a409325d9961072f666815bb8

But they detail the installation procedure in a very nice manner and with lots of explanation.

Quoting just the relevant parts:

> As of 04/11/2018, the latest version of NVIDIA driver for Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS is 384
>
> Install CUDA 9.0 [...] CUDA runfile installer can be downloaded from NVIDIA's websie,
>
> Download the "cuDNN v7.0.5 Library for Linux" tgz file (need to register for an Nvidia account).

So, binaries from Ubuntu repositories are used only for the driver.

Comment: Thanks for doing my search for me I have decided to keep going with repo's driver let me install cuda and test if it works with those drivers

Comment: No problem. If I helped, consider accepting my answer. Unless you want to for one that better/fuller addresses your question.